# SQL Conditional Where based on expression

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have this SQL Query. I want to add a conditional where so that

IF UTLI.gfc_linetransactiontypeidname = 'SF', add a WHERE clause AND UTLI.gfc_accountid='fooGuid'

```
t2 AS (
SELECT     
    SUM(UTLI.gfc_numberofunits) AS SubUnits, 
    UTLI.gfc_zoneidname AS SubZone, 
    UTLI.gfc_seasonidname AS SubSeason, 
    UTLI.gfc_linetransactiontypeidname AS SubType, 
    COUNT(UT.gfc_trans_id) as SubCount
FROM          
    Filteredgfc_UnitTransactionsLineItems AS UTLI INNER JOIN Filteredgfc_unittransactions AS UT ON UT.gfc_trans_id = UTLI.gfc_unittransactionsidname
WHERE      
    (UTLI.gfc_seasonidname = @CurrentSeason) AND (UT.gfc_trackingstatusidname IN ('PRONTO','CONTRACT PRINTED','READY TO POST')) 
    AND (UTLI.gfc_linetransactiontypeidname IN ('SBL', 'CF', 'SF'))
GROUP BY UTLI.gfc_zoneidname, UTLI.gfc_seasonidname, UTLI.gfc_linetransactiontypeidname)
```

How do you do this. I have tried splitting the gfc_linetransactiontypeidname like below but that doesn't return me any SF results. The actual data does have some results.

```
AND(
(UTLI.gfc_linetransactiontypeidname = 'SF' AND UTLI.gfc_accountid = 'fooGuid' ) 
OR
(UTLI.gfc_linetransactiontypeidname IN ('SBL', 'CF'))
)
```

Can I utilize a CASE WHEN or something to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? For example, provide a small dataset and what you want queried.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to provide a dataset, sorry. I want to query all of those SBL, CF and SF items, but when it's an SF item specifically, I need to filter them based on the fooGuid.

Comment: What happens if it is SF but doesn't have fooGuid?

Comment: Then it shouldn't be included in the query. Only SF and fooGuid should be Selected. But if it's not SF, it doesn't matter what Guid

Comment: Then your last query should work:
`AND (
(UTLI.gfc_linetransactiontypeidname = 'SF' AND UTLI.gfc_accountid = 'fooGuid' )
OR
UTLI.gfc_linetransactiontypeidname IN ('SBL', 'CF')
)`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. We ended up splitting the filters into 2 datasets and unioning them. Probably not the best way but using that AND or OR clause doesn't give us both. Thanks though.